# SplashScreen in react native

Tags: timer, react-native, splash-screen

I need to make an image as a background for the whole first screen as a SplashScreen and after some fixed time it shows the other component. 
I created two components Home and SplashScreen and here is the code i'm using:

```
componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
}
    render() {

return(

    <View>
        <SplashScreen/>
        <Home/>
    </View>

)
    }
```

Please any help or idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this in Javascript land.

Top most component would hold a flag indicating to render splash screen.
Update this flag after specified amount of time and render desired content.

Dummy implementation may look like this...

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    ready: false,
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ ready: true })
    }, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.ready === false) {
      return <Splash />
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

// Usage example:
<App>
  <RouterOrSomething />
</App>
```